# Comparing different scale ranges for one Likert scale instrument

Tags: mean, survey, scales, range

I don't believe this exact question has been asked before.  I am conducting a meta-analysis on a certain Likert scale survey instrument that has been psychometrically validated.  It is a 16 question instrument that has 4 dimensions related to the higher order latent construct with a scale range of 0-4.  The original authors tested each factor individually and published the means/standard deviation for each factor.  Most of the other studies treat it as a higher order construct and just report one mean and standard deviation for the entire instrument.  So far this is acceptable for analysis.  My problem is that some authors used the exact instrument, but changed the ranges to 1-5 or even 1-7.  How do I convert the means and standard deviations from different ranges of the exact same instrument back to the original 0-4 scale range.  I am a social scientist, not a statistician, so please be kind and use small words!  Thank you in advance.